# Nonlinear fitting function using matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, montecarlo, least-squares

I need to fit the curve that you can see in the image, that comes out from a lot of Monte Carlo simulations. I've also uploaded the data to fit in a [txt file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5a2q0w6loar51pj/output_red.txt). [image: graph]

I've tryied to fit the curve with a function of the type :

> ax*exp(b*(x^k))

with `k<1`.
The results are similar to the experimental points but still far from the fitting function I need.

I've thought to split in different equations the whole range, but I haven't reached a solution yet. I.e. a straight line for the fist part and an exponential for the third. But what about the peak?

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the [Curve Fitting Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/curvefitting/)? You can also use more complex approaches like sums of sine and cosine.

Comment: I use EzyFit because it's free

Comment: I'm sorry... the data to plot are just the first (x) and the second (y) columns. Then comes the variance, the PRSD % and the number of MC runs in order to obtain the desired error. This txt file comes out from a Fortran90 script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polynomial fitting of 8th degree:

```
close all; clear all;

fid = fopen('output_red.txt','r');
Z = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f %f');
fclose(fid);

X = log(Z{1});
Y = log(Z{2});

p = polyfit(X, Y, 8);
Y2 = polyval(p, X);

plot(exp(X), exp(Y));
hold on
plot(exp(X), exp(Y2), 'r')
legend('Original data','Fitted curve')

print('-dpng','fitted.png')
```

`p` contains polynomial coefficients `1.2737e-05 -9.1262e-04 2.7838e-02 -4.7160e-01 4.8482e+00 -3.0958e+01 1.1990e+02 -2.5649e+02 2.3480e+02`. Using higher degrees of polynomial will result in better precision.

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank You so much for the help! But what about the fitting function equation? How can I get the coefficient of the polynomial?

Comment: You should want to run script yourself to compute least-squares error and decide on degree.

Answer (score 3):

I guess your problem is not only to smooth your curve... If it is, nothing is better than a well-chosen polynomial as pointed by @divanov. So, I have nothing to say about that.

However, as I understood your data describes an empirical distribution (you told us that it came from monte carlo simulations) and if you realy want to find a function that describes your data, you might consider to estimate a well-known distribution with a heavy tail.

There are some of them already cooked in matlab toolbox. I suggest you try for instance [Weibull distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution), but you might eventually try other kinds.